# Conditional settings for a specific domain in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to have a conditional setting for a specific domian in my .htaccess file. My use case is I have dev (example.dev) and live (example.com).  The htaccess file is in my git repo but I have some settings in .htaccess that should only apply to the live site. Ideally I would like to have a conditional setting like the pseudo code below:

```
<sometag domain=my_prod_domain example.com>

#code specific to only the live domain here

</sometag>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access to the main configuration files?

If yes, then you could specify a different configuration file for your different hosts using

```
  AccessFileName .public.htaccess
```

and

```
  AccessFileName .dev.htaccess
```

And then you could work with the Include directive to load configurations common to both.

```
  Include .common.htaccess
```

Another idea would be to try to work with the If-Directives, but it all really depends on your setup and level of access to the configurations: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Edit:

Okay I think with IfDefine you can do something even more along the lines with you original though:

Start your dev. Server with `httpd -DDevServer` and have on your statements like this:

```
<IfDefine DevServer>
#Config specific for your dev. server
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine !DevServer>
#Config specific for your live server.
<IfDefine>
```

For this solution you do not need even root access on your live-server.

Comment: My dev server is local in OS X and running on MAMP Pro so I don't think this is going to work.

Comment: Well I would image MAMP already defines some variables. Maybe "MAMP"?